# POST psajax.php 404

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having trouble trying to make some links work. I have looked at the same question asked by other users but have not found any of the answers to help in my situation. When I inspect the page, I get the error:

```
POST https://novaled.cl/modules/leofeature/psajax.php?rand=1545698307561 404
core.js:1571

send @ core.js:1571
ajax @ core.js:1492
checkProductOutStock @ leofeature_cart.js:1683
(anonymous) @ leofeature_cart.js:418
dispatch @ core.js:963
elemData.handle @ core.js:939
leofeature_cart.js:1716

TECHNICAL ERROR: 

Details:
Error thrown: [object Object]
Text status: error
```

I checked all of the links and they all work well.

I tried with another browser (Firefox) and I got the following error message:

```
Error in source links: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://novaled.cl/themes/leo_sutamura/assets/css/theme.css
URL of the source link: theme.css.map[En savoir plus]

Error in source links: request failed with status 404
URL de la ressource : https://novaled.cl/themes/core.js
URL of the source link: core.js.map[En savoir plus]
```

The error happens when I click on this button:

```
<div class="button-container cart">
    <form action="https://novaled.cl/carrito" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="a45c4c87ee3b236416b716861453c102" tabindex="0">
        <input type="hidden" value="20" class="quantity_product quantity_product_1" name="quantity_product" tabindex="0">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" class="minimal_quantity minimal_quantity_1" name="minimal_quantity" tabindex="0">
        <input type="hidden" value="42" class="id_product_attribute id_product_attribute_1" name="id_product_attribute" tabindex="0">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" class="id_product" name="id_product" tabindex="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="id_customization" value="" class="product_customization_id" tabindex="0">

        <input type="hidden" class="input-group form-control qty qty_product qty_product_1" name="qty" value="1" data-min="1" tabindex="0">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-product add-to-cart leo-bt-cart leo-bt-cart_1 leo-enable" data-button-action="add-to-cart" type="submit" tabindex="0">
            <span class="leo-loading cssload-speeding-wheel"></span>
            <span class="leo-bt-cart-content">
                <i class="material-icons shopping-cart">?</i>
                <span>Carro</span>
            </span>
          </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: give us some code

Comment: There's no PHP code here or anything at all JavaScript related. Your CSS files also appear to be missing, or at least not where you expect them to be.

Comment: @tadman It seems like they are not missing since I tried the links and they all work well

Comment: Then it could be the source maps are missing and your browser is grumbling, but it's not critical. You still haven't shown any PHP or Javascript, though, so it's anyone's guess as to what's wrong.